# eslint not showing error for defined rule

Tags: typescript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-base",
    "airbnb-typescript/base",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:eslint-comments/recommended",
    "plugin:jest/recommended",
    "plugin:promise/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest"
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "eslint-comments", "jest", "promise", "import", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "no-console": "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "import/newline-after-import": ["error", { "count": 2 }],
    "import/no-default-export": "error",
    "no-use-before-define": [
      "error",
      {
        "functions": false,
        "classes": true,
        "variables": true
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": [
      "error",
      {
        "functions": false,
        "classes": true,
        "variables": true,
        "typedefs": true
      }
    ],
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": "off"
  }
}
```

Am working on node with Typescript and I have my `eslintrc.json` like this. here I have defined the rule `"import/newline-after-import": ["error", { "count": 2 }],` but when I not leaving 2 lines after  import its not showing any error

```
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express'
require('dotenv').config()
```

also `no-console: "off"` rule also does not show any warning if I remove this inside the rule.

Comment: `--print-config` can help when debugging your configuration for specific files

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--print-config